# How do I assign the testcases reviewer

Tags: django, kiwi-tcms

I configed the email settings and could receive registration email, forgot-password email etc. successfully. 
But, I can not receive the review notification email when I [input reviewer email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T6NR.png). 
I still do not find any solution in the userguide. 
So How do I fix this?

Comment: So you are not telling us what your actual problem is. Do you expect the new reviewer to receive an email when they are assigned to review a TC or the assignment operation does not work for you ?

Comment: @AlexanderTodorov The assignment operation(attached image in the question) does not work for me. Could you help me to fix this?

Comment: It works for me on https://public.tenant.kiwitcms.org/ so without logs and additional information I'm not sure how to help you. You are not giving me anything actionable.